# Clarification on c# delegates / methods

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I've used delegates in the past so I'm familiar with their use and benefits.  I've also done a lot of reading/research, but I'm trying to wrap my head around this and getting nowhere.  I'd like to use a delegate (I believe) to encapsulate some code or use a delegate within a method to call some outside code.

I'm using the same code in 20 different places to wrap an entity framework update in a transaction.  I  would like the code in one place; however, I can't do it in a method by itself because there is a middle part that will change each time.  I'm looking for some ideas / clarification on how I can best do this (.net 3.5, ms sql 2010). - thnx

code sample:

```
    void AddItem(string objDetails)
    {
        // setup method specific entity objects
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject { Details = objDetails };


        //////// Begin transaction code that I would like to encapsulate  ///////
        bool success = false;

        using (Entities data = new Entities())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.BaseSettings.CommandRetries; i++)
            {
                using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///////// BEGIN Code that I would like to change / call different each time ////////

            data.AddToSOMEOBJECTs(obj);

            //////////////// END //////////////////////////////////


            //// RETURN TO ENCAPSULATED CODE ////

                        data.SaveChanges(false);
                        transaction.Complete();
                        success = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.GetType() != typeof(UpdateException))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Unhandled db exception.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (success)
            {
                data.AcceptAllChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might be blind, but where is `a` defined?

Comment: Also in the part that you'd like to change, can you show what else you might like it to be?

Comment: the part that I would like to change will always be an update of some table in the framework; however, the tables will change each time depending on what is being updated.  I fixed the code references.  Basically, the transaction is just wrapping the updates (which need to change each time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the function a delegate (or lambda) that does the custom bit

like this

```
void AddItem<T>(string objDetails, Func<T> custom) {
  . 
  . common 
  . 
  .
  T someReturn = custom();
  . 
  . common 
  . 
}
```

add call like this perhaps:

```
Func<int> custom = () => {
     // do something custom
     return 9;
}

// Call common function    
AddItem<int>(..., custom);
```

All that matters is that the interface for the Func matches what you need.

Comment: thank you - makes sense; I had the right thought process but I haven't used this syntax before so will have to play around a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass different methods by using a delegate and an event.  Here's an example of a class that does this:

```
class SampleClass
{
    public delegate void TransactionDelegate(); 
    public event TransactionDelegate MyTransactionDelegate;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyTransactionDelegate(); 
    }

}
```

You can then use a lambda expression to pass methods to the event like this:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var test = new SampleClass(); 
        test.MyTransactionDelegate += () => {Console.WriteLine("Success");}; 
        test.DoSomething(); 
    }
}
```